# child routes doesn't work in lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angular

I am writing an Angular 8 app and I am trying to lazy load some modules and I have in this some child routes. However, the lazy load working good but the problem is child routs doesn't work and I face this error message

Error:  Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'stores/main-stores'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'stores/main-stores'

this is parent routing module

```
import { LogInComponent } from './log-in/log-in.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

const routes: Routes =
  [
    { path: '', component: LogInComponent },
    { path: 'log-in', component: LogInComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'stores', loadChildren:'./stores/stores.module#StoresModule'},


    //{ path: '**', component: LogInComponent },  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is lazy routing module

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StorsComponent } from '../home/stores/stors/stors.component';
import { MainStoresComponent } from '../home/stores/main-stores/main-stores.component';
import { InventStorComponent } from '../home/stores/invent-stor/invent-stor.component';
import { TransStoreComponent } from '../home/stores/trans-store/trans-store.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',component:StorsComponent,children:[
    {path:'MainStores',component:MainStoresComponent},
    {path:'InventStores',component:InventStorComponent},
    {path:'TransStores',component:TransStoreComponent},

  ]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StoresRoutingModule { }
```

here is lazy module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { StoresRoutingModule } from './stores-routing.module';
import { StorsComponent } from '../home/stores/stors/stors.component';
import { MainStoresComponent } from '../home/stores/main-stores/main-stores.component';
import { InventStorComponent } from '../home/stores/invent-stor/invent-stor.component';
import { TransStoreComponent } from '../home/stores/trans-store/trans-store.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    StorsComponent,
    MainStoresComponent,
    InventStorComponent,
    TransStoreComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    StoresRoutingModule,
    Ng2SmartTableModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularMyDatePickerModule,

  ]
})
export class StoresModule { }
```

heere is lazy component Html

```
<div class="stores_content">
  <div class="quickLink">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary " routerLink="main-stores" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-box"></i>معرف المخازن</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" routerLink="invent-stor"routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>جرد المخزن</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" routerLink="trans-store"routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-dolly"></i> تحويل مخزون</a>
  </div>
  <div class="storeTbls">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem happend when i click on any link to rout me to child component
so are there any way to handle it.
note:i'm a biggener

Comment: your definition of lazy loading is incorrect as per your implementation.. you need to lazy load module.. which has routes for components to be lazily loaded

Comment: you need to use the lazy loading like this: `path: 'stores', loadChildren: 'app/home/stores/store.module#StoresModule',`

Comment: sorry for missing I already did it but I miss to attach the parent routing module I will edit it

Comment: your path is "MainStores" not "main-stores"

Comment: it's working, thanks a lot for your supporting  @yanky_cranky

Answer (score 0):

See this example in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-loading-basic-example)

In your app-routing.module.ts file use in this way

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
   path: 'customers',
   loadChildren: 'src/app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
   path: 'orders',
   loadChildren: 'src/app/orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: '',
   pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```